# Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile: gmake: /usr/bin/gmake: Operation not permitted [Makefile:127: cmTC_0d1bd/fast] Error 127

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, gitlab, cicd

all. I'm working on building a CI/CD pipeline on GITLAB right now.
I'm going to use CMAKE and compound a C++ based system on ci-runner and then make a pkg
I can successfully compound a pkg locally with the image and CMakeLists.txt, but when coming to GITLAB CI/CD, there comes with ERROR.
the permission I checked on CI/CD, it shows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 255696 Feb 15  2022 /usr/bin/gmake 
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 12 15:21 /usr/bin 
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 15  2022 /usr
```

which is exactly same with the one in local.

Coming across with the ERROR that Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed

Here 's my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
  image: image_latest
  script:
    - bash -c 'abi-compliance-checker --version '
    - bash -c 'cd / && mkdir build && cd build && pwd '
    - bash -c 'cd /build && pwd && cmake -S /builds/System -B /build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release '
    - bash -c 'cd /build && make install '
```

I added below code on CMakeLists.txt at the very first beginning:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- **Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed**
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- **Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed**
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Compiler is GNU
-- Compiler version = 11
-- Set up for version = 11
```

ERROR log:

```
::::::::::::::
/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
::::::::::::::
The system is: Linux - 5.4.0-107-generic - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  
The output was:
0
Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"
The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "/build/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CompilerIdC/a.out"
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/g++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  
The output was:
0
Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"
The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "/build/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"
::::::::::::::
/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
::::::::::::::
**Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile** with the following output:
Change Dir: /build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_0d1bd/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d1bd.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d1bd.dir/build
gmake: /usr/bin/gmake: Operation not permitted
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_0d1bd/fast] Error 127
**Detecting CXX compiler ABI info failed to compile** with the following output:
Change Dir: /build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_9f20e/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f20e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f20e.dir/build
gmake: /usr/bin/gmake: Operation not permitted
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_9f20e/fast] Error 127
```

Resolve the ERROR that I can compound the pkg successfully via CMAKE

Comment: The error message `gmake: /usr/bin/gmake: Operation not permitted` suggest that something wrong with permissions on file `/usr/bin/gmake`. BTW, setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS` normally implies that you want to **supress** some problems with your compiler or environment. You are better to **solve** that problem with compiler/environment before trying to solve other environment-related problems, like your current one.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev @Tsyvarev, thanks for your comment, when i removed CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS, there's same error and with "Detecting C compile features - failed".  I can successfully compound a pkg locally with the same image and CMakeLists.txt, but when coming to GITLAB CI/CD, there comes with ERROR.  As can be seen in the log above, it can detect the complier located at /usr/bin/gcc, very confusing and don't have any idea about how to resolve this ERROR, can you kindly give some hits on it? i'm still quite new to C++, thanks.

Comment: @KrisWONG There's something different about `/usr/bin/gmake` in the CI/CD container.  Add something like `ls -ladL /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/gmake` to your scripts and you might see something wrong with permissions, for example  `-rwxr-x---.  1 root root 240768 Oct 21  2021 /usr/bin/gmake`.  If you see that, only `root` would have permission to actually run `gmake`.  It could also be a problem with directory permissions in `/usr` or `/usr/bin`.  Or `/usr/bin/gmake` could be a soft-link into a filesystem that's mounted with the `noexec` option.  There's a lot of possibilities.

Comment: hi Andrew @AndrewHenle thank you for your reply, i just checked the permission on CI/CD, it shows `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 255696 Feb 15  2022 /usr/bin/gmake`, 
`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 12 15:21 /usr/bin` and 
`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 15  2022 /usr` which is exactly same with the one showing in the local, the local is also with this kind of permission but can compound the pkg successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this ERROR by re-generated a new GITLAB-RUNNER, turns out the old gitlab-runner has something wrong so that fail to compound a pkg. I just upgrade my ci-runner to the updatedst version.